# Overlay a DIV on top of another element

Tags: jquery, css

Basically I have an IFRAME that displays a given page. I want to position a number of DIVs on top of specific elements **within** this IFRAME. I am not able to edit the CSS of the IFRAME source page.

Currently, I am using jQuery to append the DIVs within the IFRAME:

```
$('#portal').contents().find('.callout').append('<div class="overlay">Test</div>');
```

(`#portal` is the IFRAME, `.callout` is the target DIV)

So now I just need div.overlay to be displayed on top of / over the target DIV. Is this possible to do?

Comment: The `iframe` is loaded from the same domain as the parent page, correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you could position the element `absolute` or `relative` to a container, then set the position accordingly.

```
.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    top: 10px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```